# Run-time error 13: Type mismatch , If two cells (or more) selected and deleted on the same row of target

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to intersect change on column E with some conditions, one of the conditions is to firing if target changed value is not null , the effect of event applied without problem, **But** If two cells (or more) selected and deleted on the same row of target
I got this error

> Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

This the cause of error `Target.value <> ""`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing And _
      Target.Columns.Count = 1 And _
      Target.Row > 1 And _
      Target.value <> "" Then
 
     Application.EnableEvents = False
       'Some codes here
     Application.EnableEvents = True
 
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Appreciate for yours comments and answers.

Comment: `Target.value <> ""` cannot be used for matching a potential array... It will return the first area and no error if this one contains only one cell. For instance `Range($H$3,$H$5,$H$7)` (a discontinuous range) will return the value of H3. But if there are more than one cell in the first area it will raise an error...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,sure your are correct, and I modified the code (on my PC) and put `Target.value <> ""` on a sperate IF and now works, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only check `Target.Columns.Count` but `Target` can also be multiple rows. And then `Target.value` is an array of values, and an array cannot be compared to `= ""` without looping.

So replace `Target.Columns.Count = 1` with `Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1` to ensure that `Target` is only one cell, or alternatively loop through all the cells in `Target` that intersect with your range `E:E`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E:E"))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell in AffectedRange
            ' here you can handle each cell that has changed in E:E
        Next Cell
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Off topic note:

It you use `Application.EnableEvents = False` make sure that if an error occurs you turn the events back on! Otherwise your events are turned off in the entire Excel until you close it.

Comment: It works, but I don't understand if `Target is only one cell` So by logic It has one value , I am still learning vba

Comment: @Waleed in the procedure it is defined `Target As Range` so `Target` is a range of cells. This can be any amount of cells from one cell to all cells in the sheet. So if it is more than one cell it has more than one value (in this case an 2 dimensional array of values). So if you want to use `Target.Value = ""` you need to first test if `Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1` because if that is not the case you cannot compare `Target.Value = ""`.